# Is it possible that if I multiply 2 floats the result will be different then multiplication of 2 decimals?

Tags: python, django

I am calculating a field in my view file

```
data_dict = { 'quantity_order': float(bom.quantity) * float(quantity)}
```

I added float conversion since I was getting a different problem:

> "can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'Decimal'"

In model both fields are defined as decimal

```
quantity_order = models.DecimalField(max_digits=19, decimal_places=3)
```

one of the fields is received via url regular expression

```
 url(r'^production/order/new/(?P<pk_bom>\d+)/(?P<pk_soproduct>\d+)/(?P<uri>\S+)/(?P<quantity>\d+(\.\d{1,3}))/$',views.Production_order_new, name="production_order_new"),
```

So the issue is that sometimes the calculation is not correct. 
For example if both quantity values are `44` then it gets calculated correctly, but when one value is `44 * 666` the result will be `443556.000`

Can it be the converting values to float before multiplication is causing this error?

Comment: Converting to float won't produce a wrong result like that. Floats are just as good as decimals when the numbers are small and have no fractions.

Comment: `443556` is `666 * 666`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'Decimal'"

What this actually means is that one of your operands is a sequence and the other is a Decimal. Ie, one of `bom.quantity` or `quantity` is a sequence and not an int, float or decimal.

```
data_dict = { 'quantity_order': float(bom.quantity) * float(quantity)}
```

A sequence can be multplied by an int.

```
seq = [1,2,3]
seq * 2 # produces  [1,2,3,1,2,3]
```

but

```
seq * 2.5 # produces can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to convert it to float? Decimal is good enough for this. The result is still the same even if you don't convert it.

If you really want to convert it for some reason then use this method:

```
data_dict = { 'quantity_order': float(bom.quantity * quantity)}
```

but this will not change the number of decimal places.

Comment: added float conversion since I was getting a different problem:

"can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'Decimal'"

Comment: Where did you get the bom.quantity and quantity? and what's the datatype? Is it integer or float? If float then it will throw an error since float and Decimal can't be together.

Comment: Does it comes from the request?

Comment: I mentioned in question what is the type and from where they are coming.They are both of the same Decimal type.